# Need help in conversion of C# code to F# in .NET Core 6

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

My C# code for file upload Web API works perfectly fine. My F# knowledge is limited so pardon me if anywhere I am wrong.

C# code

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LargeFilesSample.Controllers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// controller for upload large file
    /// </summary>
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class FileUploadController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<FileUploadController> _logger;

        public FileUploadController(ILogger<FileUploadController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Action for upload large file
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Request to this action will not trigger any model binding or model validation,
        /// because this is a no-argument action
        /// </remarks>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpPost]
        [Route(nameof(UploadLargeFile))]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadLargeFile()
        {
            var request = HttpContext.Request;

            // validation of Content-Type
            // 1. first, it must be a form-data request
            // 2. a boundary should be found in the Content-Type
            if (!request.HasFormContentType ||
                !MediaTypeHeaderValue.TryParse(request.ContentType, out var mediaTypeHeader) ||
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(mediaTypeHeader.Boundary.Value))
            {
                return new UnsupportedMediaTypeResult();
            }

            var reader = new MultipartReader(mediaTypeHeader.Boundary.Value, request.Body);
            var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();

            // This sample try to get the first file from request and save it
            // Make changes according to your needs in actual use
            while (section != null)
            {
                var hasContentDispositionHeader = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(section.ContentDisposition,
                    out var contentDisposition);

                if (hasContentDispositionHeader && contentDisposition.DispositionType.Equals("form-data") &&
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentDisposition.FileName.Value))
                {
                    // Don't trust any file name, file extension, and file data from the request unless you trust them completely
                    // Otherwise, it is very likely to cause problems such as virus uploading, disk filling, etc
                    // In short, it is necessary to restrict and verify the upload
                    // Here, we just use the temporary folder and a random file name

                    // Get the temporary folder, and combine a random file name with it
                    var fileName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
                    var saveToPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), fileName);

                    using (var targetStream = System.IO.File.Create(saveToPath))
                    {
                        await section.Body.CopyToAsync(targetStream);
                    }

                    return Ok();
                }

                section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
            }

            // If the code runs to this location, it means that no files have been saved
            return BadRequest("No files data in the request.");
        }
    }
}
```

But when I am trying to convert the same to f# it gives me an error. As I am new F# what ever I do I did to convert the code but is not working

F# code

```
open Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens

open Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

open Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration

open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities
open Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
open Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers
open System.IO
open System.Threading.Tasks

[<ApiController>]
[<Route("[controller]")>]
type FileUploadController(configuration : IConfiguration, logger : ILogger<UserAccountController>,
    tokenValidationParams: TokenValidationParameters) as self =
    inherit SootchyControllerBase(configuration, logger)

    [<HttpPost>]
    [<HttpPost("Upload")>]
    member this.UploadLargeFile() = 
        let mutable request = HttpContext.Request
        if not request.HasFormContentType || not (MediaTypeHeaderValue.TryParse (request.ContentType, (* ERROR UnknownNode "DeclarationExpressionSyntax" var mediaTypeHeader *))) || string.IsNullOrEmpty (mediaTypeHeader.Boundary.Value)
        then return new UnsupportedMediaTypeResult()
        let mutable reader = new MultipartReader(mediaTypeHeader.Boundary.Value, request.Body)
        let mutable section = (* ERROR UnknownNode "AwaitExpressionSyntax" await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync() *)
        while (section <> Unchecked.defaultof<_>) do
            let mutable hasContentDispositionHeader = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse (section.ContentDisposition, (* ERROR UnknownNode "DeclarationExpressionSyntax" var contentDisposition *))
            if hasContentDispositionHeader && contentDisposition.DispositionType.Equals ("form-data") && not (string.IsNullOrEmpty (contentDisposition.FileName.Value))
            then 
                let mutable fileName = Path.GetRandomFileName ()
                let mutable saveToPath = Path.Combine ((Path.GetTempPath ()), fileName)
                let __ = 
                    use targetStream = System.IO.File.Create (saveToPath)
                    (* ERROR UnknownNode "AwaitExpressionSyntax" await section.Body.CopyToAsync(targetStream) *)
                return (Ok ())
            section <- (* ERROR UnknownNode "AwaitExpressionSyntax" await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync() *)
        BadRequest ("No files data in the request.")
```

[image]

Can anyone help me convert the code?

Comment: I think one of the major problems you're facing here is how to convert C# async/await logic into F#. To do that, you'll probably need to get familiar with [task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/task-expressions) or [async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/async-expressions) computation expressions.

Comment: `return` doesn't mean the same thing in F# as it does in C# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/computation-expressions#return

Comment: There is no 1:1 with co-routines. Looking at the how you've declared everything to be mutable, learning the basics from https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com might be a good investment.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things that you will need to get this to work:

- `task` computation expression, which is an F# way of doing `async`/`await`. This means you wrap your code in a `task { .. }` block and can then use `let!` and `do!` in place of `await`
- Recursive function to replace the imperative loop with `return` (this seems the easiest option here, although there are other options). The idea is to write a function that processes one section and either returns or calls itself repeatedly to process the next section.

I would recommend starting with something simpler as this is quite complex code block to translate if you are still learning about the above. However, here is a sketch of how you would do this (looking only at the `while` loop part):

```
member this.UploadLargeFile() = task {
  // (more code here omitted)
  let reader = new MultipartReader(mediaTypeHeader.Boundary.Value, request.Body)

  // Recursive function to process a single section
  let rec processSection (section:MultipartSection) = task {
    if section = null then
      return BadRequest("No files data in the request.")
    let hasContentDispositionHeader, contentDisposition = 
      ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(section.ContentDisposition)
    if hasContentDispositionHeader && contentDisposition.DispositionType.Equals("form-data") 
      && not (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentDisposition.FileName.Value)) then
      let fileName = Path.GetRandomFileName()
      let saveToPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), fileName)
      use targetStream = System.IO.File.Create(saveToPath)
      do! section.Body.CopyToAsync(targetStream)
      return Ok()
    else 
      section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
      return! tryNextSection() }

  // Read the first section and process it
  let! section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync()
  return! processSection section }
```